# Kendo UI datasource OData transport submit function never called

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, datasource, transport

i have created a kendo UI grid, with datasource. I want to implement batch mode. I found this article [batch editing odata](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/batch-editing-odata). I add in my code sumbit function but never calls.

Also from Kendo documentation [transport submit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.submit).

The problem is that this sumbit function never calls!!

Update and create called as well and in Telerik configuration say: "Typically, you have the transport.read and transport.submit operations defined together. The transport.create, transport.update and transport.delete operations will not be executed in this case."

i have a lot of code that no need to see.. the problem is that grid is batch == true, and the submit function never call.

```
$scope.grid.dataSource = {
serverSorting: true,
type: "odata",
batch: $scope.config.grid.dataSource.batch,
transport: {
    read: {
        url: $scope.config.grid.dataSource.readUrl,
        complete: function (e) {
            $scope.notification.hide();
            if (e.statusText != 'error') {
                $scope.handler.enabledButtons();
            }
            else {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.notification.show('Something went wrong while loading data. Please try later.' + ' Error code: ' + e.status, "error");
                });
                $scope.handler.disableButtons();
                $("#grid" + $scope.config.id).data("kendoGrid").refresh();
            }
        }
    },
    submit: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    },
        create: {
            url: function (data) {
                return $scope.config.grid.dataSource.crudUrl;
            },
            type: "POST",
            complete: function (e) {
                $scope.notification.hide();
                if (e.status == '201')
                    $scope.notification.show('Item created successfully.', "info");
                else {
                    try {
                        $scope.notification.show('Create failed. ' + (JSON.parse(e.responseText))["odata.error"].message.value, 'error');
                    }
                    catch (exception) {
                        $scope.notification.show('Create failed. An error occurred.' + ' ( Error code: ' + e.status + ' )', 'error');
                    }
                    $scope.handler.createFailed();
                }
            }
        },
        update: {
            url: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                if ($scope.config.grid.model.guid)
                    return $scope.config.grid.dataSource.crudUrl + "(guid'" + data[$scope.config.grid.model.id] + "')";
                return $scope.config.grid.dataSource.crudUrl + "('" + data[$scope.config.grid.model.id] + "')";
            },
            type: "PUT",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                if ($scope.config.grid.dataSource.transport.beforeSend)
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('If-Match', '*');
            },
            complete: function (e) {
                $scope.notification.hide();
                if (e.status == '204') {
                    $scope.notification.show('Item Saved successfully.', "info");
                }
                else {
                    try{
                        $scope.notification.show('Update failed. ' + (JSON.parse(e.responseText))["odata.error"].message.value, 'error');
                    }
                    catch (exception) {
                        $scope.notification.show('Update failed. An error occurred.' + ' ( Error code: ' + e.status + ' )', 'error');
                    }
                    $scope.handler.updateFailed();
                }
            }
        },
        destroy: {
            url: function (data) {
                if ($scope.config.grid.model.guid)
                    return $scope.config.grid.dataSource.crudUrl + "(guid'" +  data[$scope.config.grid.model.id]+ "')";
                return $scope.config.grid.dataSource.crudUrl + "('" + data[$scope.config.grid.model.id] + "')";
            },
            type: "DELETE",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                if ($scope.config.grid.dataSource.transport.beforeSend)
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('If-Match', '*')
            },
            complete: function (e) {
                $scope.notification.hide();
                if (e.status == '204')
                    $scope.notification.show('Deleted successfully.', "info");
                else {
                    try {
                        $scope.notification.show('Delete failed. ' + (JSON.parse(e.responseText))["odata.error"].message.value, 'error');
                    }
                    catch (exception) {
                        $scope.notification.show('Delete failed. An error occurred.' + ' ( Error code: ' + e.status + ' )', 'error');
                    }
                    $scope.handler.destroyFailed();         
                }
            }
        },
    parameterMap: function (options, type) {
        if (type == "read")
            return kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options, type);
        else {
            if (type == 'create' || type == 'update') {
                data = {}
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.config.grid.dataSource.transport.data.length; i++) {
                    data[$scope.config.grid.dataSource.transport.data[i]] = options[$scope.config.grid.dataSource.transport.data[i]];
                }
                return kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(data, type);
            }
        }
    },
},
error: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
},
schema: {
    model: {
        id: $scope.config.grid.model.id,
        fields: $scope.config.grid.model.fields
    },
    data: function (data) {
        if (data.value) {
            return data.value;
        }
        delete data["odata.metadata"];
        return [data];
    },
    total: function (data) {
        if (typeof data.value == 'undefined')
            return data.d;
        return data['odata.count'];
    }
},
pageSize: 30,
serverPaging: true,
serverFiltering: true,
serverSorting: true,
sort: $scope.config.grid.dataSource.sort,
```

};

batch is true.
And goes on error case with status : "parsererror"
and errorThrown
:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4 at n.parseJSON (http://localhost:12187/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:5309) at vc (http://localhost:12187/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:7397) at x (http://localhost:12187/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:10802) at XMLHttpRequest. (http://localhost:12187/Scripts/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:14767)
message
:
"Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4"

Comment: Add the Grid configuration as well

Comment: ok i update my post